# Size of the file uploaded in javascript using hidden IFrame

Tags: javascript, html, file, file-upload

I am using the hidden IFrame in my HTML to upload a file. I want to find the size of the file uploaded. How can it be done.

```
 function fileselect(iframeid,ctrlFilePath,ctrlHdnFilePath,ctrlHdnFileName,taskName,filelist,ctrlhdnstoredfilename,ctrlhdnurlpath)
 {
      var frame=document.getElementById(iframeid);
      frame.setAttribute("filepath", ctrlFilePath);
      frame.setAttribute("filename", ctrlHdnFileName);
      frame.setAttribute("urlpath", ctrlhdnurlpath);
      var wdf = window.document.getElementById(iframeid).contentWindow.document.forms[0];
      var ctrlFileUpload = wdf.file;
      ctrlFileUpload.click();
      if (ctrlFileUpload.value != "") 
      {
           document.getElementById(ctrlFilePath).value=ctrlFileUpload.value;
           fileupload();
      }
 }

 function fileupload()
 {
      var objIFrame = document.getElementsByTagName("IFRAME");
      for(var i=0; i<objIFrame.length; i++)
      {
           var wdf = window.document.getElementById(objIFrame[i].id).contentWindow.document.forms[0];
           var ctrlFileUpload = wdf.file;
           if (ctrlFileUpload.value != "") {
                wdf.submit();
                alert("File is " + wdf.file.size + " bytes in size");
           }
           delete wdf;
           wdf=null;
      }
 }
```

I tried the above code `wdf.file.size` but every time i get the size of the file uploaded as 20 bytes even when it isn't.

EDIT:

I also tried `wdf.file.files[0].size` but i am getting `wdf.file.files` as undefined.

the html loaded in the IFrame.

```
 <form name="process" id="process" method="post" action="xyz.jsp" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type=file  id="file" name="file" >

 </form>
```

Looking for something that works on IE6+

Answer (score 0):

I got this code that works on IE 11.

```
 var myFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
 var filepath = document.upload.file.value;
 var thefile = myFSO.getFile(filepath);
 var size = thefile.size;
 alert(size + " bytes");
```